# Sort Time Series Data in the existing field with time series key name in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

If I have a time series scheme down below, how do I sort by time series Key Name(ex. 20180705) in "Info" field and get all Values
db.MyCollection.find({"A":"JOHN"}).sort(.....)

```
{
"Name": "JOHN",
"ID": ...,
"Info":{
"20180705":{"Value":"100"},
"20180704":{"Value":"90"},
"20180703":{"Value":"150"},
"20180702":{"Value":"70"},
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use collections module:

```
import collections

dict = {"Info":{
    "20180705":{"Value":"100"},
    "20180704":{"Value":"90"},
    "20180703":{"Value":"150"},
    "20180702":{"Value":"70"},
               }
       }
collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dict["Info"].items()))
```